# Проблема с различием & и and. Как работает алгоритм проверки на степень двойки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, функции

Задача:

Учитывая целое число `n`, *вернуть* `True` если это степень двойки. В противном случае возвращайтесь `False`.

Пример 1:

```
Вход: n = 1
 Выход: правда
 Объяснение: 2 ** 0 = 1
```

Пример 2:

```
Ввод: n = 16
 Вывод: верно
 Объяснение: 2 ** 4 = 16
```

Пример 3:

```
Вход: n = 3
 Выход: ложь
```

---

**Проблема**

Задачу я решил, но увидел решение другого человека. ->

```
def isPowerOfTwo(self, n: int) -> bool:
    return n and not (n & n - 1)
```

Как это работает? А также вопрос будет: если мы заменим & на and, то результат будет некорректный, почему?

Comment: Генри Уоррен младший, "Алгоритмические трюки для программистов".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как это работает:

K-я степень двойки в двоичном виде выглядят как один единичный бит на `k`-м месте `00001000`. Если отнять единицу, то получится число с `k` единичными битами `00000111`. При побитовом `&` таких чисел всегда выйдёт ноль.

```
 00001000
& 
 00000111
---------
 00000000
```

Поэтому выражение `(n & n - 1) == 0` можно использовать для определения, является ли `n` степенью двойки. В данном случае для получения `True` используется обратное выражение и логическое отрицание `not`.

Нужно также учесть случай, когда само `n==0`, поэтому два выражения объединяются логическим `and`

Comment: Забыли добавить что `n & (n - 1)` удаляет из числа младший бит. А в степени двойки такой бит - единственный.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy Я же написал про один единичный бит. Более широкое применение операции мне показалось излишне здесь описывать. Вы про Уоррена написали, при желании посмотрят.

Answer (score 1):

`and` является логическим оператором, тогда как `&` - побитовым И

Пример:

```py
>>> x = 0b0101
>>> x
5
>>> y = 0b0110
>>> y
6
>>> z = x & y
>>> z
4
>>> # 0b0100 - 4 в двоичном виде
>>>
>>> z = x and y
>>> z
6
```

Comment: вы бы еще объяснили спрашивающему, почему при логическом сложении у вас получается 6